# Cómo inserto datos a la tabla (Treeview Tkinter) desde otro documento.py?

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero hacer los cálculos en otro docoumento.py y quiero insertar esos cálculos en la tabla (treeview). Es decir quiero insertar datos a la tabla desde otro documento.py

**Prueba.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns = ("#0"), height = 8)

tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 2)
tree.heading("#0", text  = "ID")
tree.heading("#1", text  = "name")
#---------------------------------------------------------------
#HELP ME: I need to insert data from another document.py
tree.insert("", 'end',text = "id_1", values=("Erick"))
#---------------------------------------------------------------

root.mainloop()
```

Atención!!!!!!!!! Realmente quiero hacer algo como esto, pero no funciona

**Prueba.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns = ("#0"), height = 8)

tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 2)
tree.heading("#0", text  = "ID")
tree.heading("#1", text  = "name")

root.mainloop()
```

**other.py**

```
import prueba

prueba.tree.insert("", 'end',text = "id_1", values=("Erick"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido Dayamon5 c:

## Explicación

El problema está cuando importas el modulo `prueba`, y se ejecuta esta línea `root.mainloop()`. En la ultima línea mencionada, se inicia el loop de Tkinter, el cual no termina hasta que cierres la ventana. Para entenderlo mejor, piénsalo como un `while True`.

Cuando cierras la ventana, el dato se intenta ingresar, pero como el Treeview ya no existe, tira error.

## Solución

Puedes hacer que los datos se ingresen a través de una función proveniente de other.py de la siguiente manera:

---

**prueba.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

from other import ingresa_datos

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns = ("#0"), height = 8)

tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 2)
tree.heading("#0", text  = "ID")
tree.heading("#1", text  = "name")


# Nótese que ingreso los datos antes de iniciar el loop de tkinter.
ingresa_datos(tree)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**other.py**

```
def ingresa_datos(tree):
    tree.insert("", 'end',text = "id_1", values=("Erick"))
```

---